# Appointment System with Google Calendar API (Timeslots) React/NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, google-calendar-api, appointment

I am currently developing an appointment calendar with React and NodeJS using the Google Calendar API. The goal is to archive the following:

Step 1: User selects the desired Date in Calendar (done)
Step 2: Show Free 30 Minutes Timeslots in between the opening hours (done)
Step 3: Book Appointment and add to Calendar (done)

But now the problem is, that each timeslot can have 10 individual bookings and I want to show how much is left (e.g 3 People booked the slot at 15:30, I want to show that there are 7 Slots left) Currently if one booked the 15:30 slot it is removed. That is because I use a FreeBusy Query, and this only shows me the busy time not how many events there are.

My first thought was to save the bookings also in a database and then look for every timeslot how many people booked before, but this seems like not the best solution.

Do you have any better ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion but maybe for each of the event placed on the calendar you could attach an extended property to mark the event as booked.

```
"extendedProperties": {
    "shared": {
      "booked": "false",}
    }
```

https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource

Then whenever someone books an event, you could mark that event as booked by changing the extended property mentioned. To display the amount of event that are free to book you could filter the list of events by timeMin, timeMax of the selected Timeslot and count the number of events that are marked free or booked.

Comment: Thank's for your suggestion, i will give it a try :-)